# how do i divide two results of nested queries

Tags: sql

how do i divide two results of nested queries?? what i mean is:   i have a stored procedure

```
SELECT s.sheep_id,
       ( s.sheepThatHadBirth / ( s.sheepThatHadBirth + s1.sheepThatNotHadBirth ) ) * 100
FROM   (SELECT sheep_id,
               Count(*) AS sheepThatHadBirth
        FROM   FemaleSheep_Has_Wave
        WHERE  pregnencies_succeded = 1
        GROUP  BY sheep_id)AS s
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT sheep_id,
                          Count(*) AS sheepThatNotHadBirth
                   FROM   FemaleSheep_Has_Wave
                   WHERE  pregnencies_succeded = 0
                   GROUP  BY sheep_id)AS s1
```

the result is not right becouse of the cross join i think
please help thanks

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? What is the datatype of `pregnencies_succeded`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `JOIN` at all here

```
SELECT sheep_id,
       100.0 * Sum(CASE
                     WHEN pregnencies_succeded = 1 THEN 1
                     ELSE 0
                   END) / Count(*) AS pregnencies_succeded_pct
FROM   FemaleSheep_Has_Wave
GROUP  BY sheep_id
```

Comment: Or just `Sum(CAST(pregnencies_succeded AS INT)) / Count(*)` possibly.

Comment: Or even just . . . avg(1.0*pregnancies_succeeded).